# AttributeError: 'Cycler' object has no attribute 'change_key'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to `import matplotlib` on Ubuntu. I reinstalled matplotlib from source because i couldn't use the `TkAgg` backend. Now I'm facing a new problem which I cannot solve and also can't find the solution anywhere. I'm using Python 3.5.
I have this error showing me when i run a simple import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b3+1955.g888bf17-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1174, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b3+1955.g888bf17-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1017, in rc_params
    return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b3+1955.g888bf17-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1149, in rc_params_from_file
    config = RcParams([(key, default) for key, (default, _) in iter_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b3+1955.g888bf17-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 901, in __init__
    self[k] = v
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b3+1955.g888bf17-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 918, in __setitem__
    cval = self.validate[key](val)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0b3+1955.g888bf17-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 844, in validate_cycler

    cycler_inst.change_key(prop, norm_prop)
AttributeError: 'Cycler' object has no attribute 'change_key'
```

I think it has maybe something to do with cycler import from rcsetup.py because there is a comment which says that:

```
# Don't let the original cycler collide with our validating cycler
```

So the original whatever this is, is colliding with their cycler?

How can I fix this? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just checked the version of cycler and it was outdated. Just update cycler with

`sudo pip3 install --upgrade cycler`

or

`sudo -H python3 -m pip install --upgrade cycler`.

Comment: Don't forget you can use `--user` instead of `sudo`

Comment: The second one worked for me in Ubuntu OS with Jupyter